# How to hide a tab bar in a view-based/tab-bar application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, view, tabbar

I'm working at a simple view-based iPhone application.
From the main screen of the App you can navigate to 4 different views.
One of these views consists of a tab bar.
Because this is not the normal approach I used a workaround without a UITabController.

To accomplish this I made use of this topic:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2099944?start=0&tstart=0

And this example code:
http://pymbian.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/pymbian/stuff/testtab_raynewbie/Classes/

With some small modifications this works.
Only I have one last bug when I want to return to the home view from the tabbed view, the tab bar stays in the bottom of the screen.

I tried several approaches described here.

```
myTabBar.hidden = YES
hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES
```

But none seem to work....
I think the problem is somewhere in the strange structure of views UI controllers. Because now the structure looks like this.

```
MainViewController
- ViewController with TabBar
  - tab1viewcontroller
  - tab2viewcontroller
- other viewcontrollers
```

And going back to the main view is done in the tab1viewcontroller where I can't do anything to the TabBar. In all the other views I go back with this code:

```
-(IBAction) BackAction:(id)sender {

mainControllerView = [[MainControllerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainControllerView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:mainControllerView.view];
[mainControllerView.view release];

}
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: I have same probem dude .U got any solution?, if you know any thing plz explain thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide the tab bar when pushed from previous view.

```
LoginViewController *loginViewObj =[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
loginViewObj.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
```

`LoginViewController` is the view to be pushed where tab bar is not required. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in view-controller where you want to hide tabbar

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.tabBarController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 560)];
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [self.tabBarController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

}
```

Comment: this is a crappy way to hide the tab bar, you shouldn't spread it this way.. sorry for the down vote.